# Why floats or doubles get written as integers?

Tags: c++

In the following program

```
#include <fstream>

int main(){
    
    
    std::ofstream fs_;
    fs_.open("test.txt");
    

   fs_<<1.f;
   fs_<<"   ";
   fs_<<1.0;
    
    fs_.flush();
    fs_.close();
    
return 0;   
}
```

Why the resulting file has written

```
1   1
```

instead of `1.0 1.0` ? And is there a way to write them as floats or doubles?

I should have added that with floats with a lot of decimals I don't want them to be truncated.

So far with the suggested solution `1.034255` becomes `1.03` with precision of 2

Rather than the "duplicate" that this question was closed for, this question is more related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489627/setting-minimum-number-of-decimal-places-for-stdostream-precision)

Comment: Try: `fs_<<std::fixed<<std::setprecision(5)<<1.0;`

Comment: Thanks. `setprecision` dealt with the elimination of the decimals but as a side effect now truncates other floats to the number of decimals :(  Is there a way to not truncate them? set the minimum precision  somehow?

Comment: `instead of 1.0 1.0 ?` By default, trailing zeros are removed, with the dot. `floats with a lot of decimals I don't want them to be truncated.` Sooo `1/3f` is inifnite? For computer, most floats have endless decimals. `now truncates other floats to the number of decimals :( Is there a way to not truncate them?` Each float has endless decimals. You can print for exmaple with 40 decimals, and then parse the result as a string remove zeros up to the excluding the last one before `.`.